# Mean value of linear regression with another regression

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression, linear-regression

> A survey is given to adults in each family. $a$ is the age of the
> adult,and $b$ is the age of the oldest child - these are recorded. The
> ages of the oldest child are summarized in the following box and
> whisker diagram:
>
> [image]
>
> The regression line of $a$ on $b$ is $a = 7/4b+20$, and the regression
> line of $b$ on $c$ is $b = 1/2a-9$
>
> Find the mean age of all the adults surveyed.

I tried solving the system of equations for $a$ and $b$, which gives me $a = 34, b = 8$. Meaning (I guess) that the average age of the adults is 34, isn't it? Because the answer is wrong according to my teacher, but he doesn't explain me why.

Comment: How is $c$ defined?

Comment: I'm guessing that $c$ is just a typo, and should be $a$? In any case, yes, this seems right to me. With ordinary least squares, for a fit $y = mx + c$, it must hold that the sample means of $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$ are related as $\bar{y} = m \bar{x} + c$, and with the two regression lines you're getting two equations in $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$. The incorrectness could be that you don't explicitly point out or derive that the means have to satisfy this relation, in other words, your answer may be correct, but insufficiently justified. I'd just ask the teacher, though.

Comment: Incidentally, the $\frac74$ suggests that parents are tending to get younger when their first child is born over time  ($a-b$ seems to be positively correlated with $b$ where $b$ is how long ago that first child was born) - it would be a more realistic question if both coefficients were slightly less than $1$